# Drupal 7 theme css added to a views page when used as the front/home page

Tags: css, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-jcarousel

I am a CSS noob and I created a carousel using jCarousel. It works like it should as a page and with tabbed menus. The problem is the theme adds CSS to it when I go to /admin/config/system/site-information and make the view the default front page. It adds list bullets over each carousel item and changes the displayed item location.

I want to remove these bullets from the view but not the entire site.  The development site can be seen at http://delphos.lib.oh.us/NewSite/

If you click on one of the "tabs" (red boxed buttons) the display problem goes away.

Any help would be appreciated.

TBG

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for this line:

```
.art-postcontent ul>li:before, .art-post ul>li:before, .art-textblock ul>li:before {}
```

You can remove the whole line, or just remove the content attribute. Either should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but wouldn't this remove the bullets from the entire site?  This is part of the theme's style.css. I guess I'm looking for a way to override them just for the carousel view page.